# MIPS pipeline processor how to implement SLTU

Tags: mips, pipeline, processor

I am doing a 32 bit pipeline processor. The way I implement SLT is by using the sign bit and the overflow.

```
op_alu_result = {31'b0,op_alu_overflow ^ w_alu_result[31]};
```

However this is not right for SLTU. The result is not correct. Is there any way to implement SLTU similarly?